# How to create pop-ups with graphs on point layers?

Tags: qgis, postgresql, popup, graph

I have a PostgreSQL database which is refreshed every 10 minutes and I need to create graphs in a pop-up with the data. When I click, a pop-up (or annotation) should appear. How can I make it possible?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be to create a layer action similar to what is described in [A python layer action to open a wikipedia page in QGIS](http://linfiniti.com/2012/03/a-python-layer-action-to-open-a-wikipedia-page-in-qgis/). Basically:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QUrl; from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebView;  myWV = QWebView(None);
myWV.load(QUrl('http://wikipedia.org/wiki/[% "name_0" %]')); myWV.show()
```

A python package which is often used in plugins which create graphs is called [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/). It can create all kinds of graphs. Since you didn't specify which kind you need - this gives you flexibility but requires some coding.